# Python Creating Classes Code

Tags: python, class

Sorry for the poor title, didnt know what to put.

When creating a class in python i use this,

```
class NewClass(object):
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
```

but why is it different to this?

```
class NewClass(object):
    def __init__(self,name):
        name = self.name
```

Surely the equals sign means it is the same process? Why is different?

Comment: `=` is **assignment**, not an equality test. `self.name = name` sets the attribute `name` on the object referenced by `self`. `name = self.name` sets a local variable `name`.

Comment: Assigning `name` to `self.name` and assigning `self.name` to `name` surely is different…!?

Comment: This has nothing to do with classes, but is simple assignment. Rather than asking questions here you would benefit from reading a basic introduction to programming.

Comment: `a = b` means `change a to be equal to b`. That is different from `change b to be equal to a`.

Comment: I agree that the usage of the equal sign for an assignment can be confusing for a layman, `← ` would probably have been better, but `=` is used in all programming languages (or almost). You will have to deal with it.

Comment: Why do i have so many downvotes, its a question that i wasnt sure of so i asked for an explanation

Comment: We expect a certain minimum familiarity with programming. Any basic programming course/tutorial/book would explain the difference between `=` and `==`.

Comment: but i wasnt asking the difference between = and == i was asking why the two things had to be a certain way around the = sign

Comment: Which should be obvious if you understand what `=` does, no?

Comment: obviously not thats why i asked the question

Comment: Well, `=` has to have *some* directionality. One side is assigned to the other. They can't both be assigned to each other or somehow otherwise be equal and interchangeable.

Comment: So I guess the answer boils down to: *because that's how `=` is defined.* The *right hand side* is assigned to the *left hand side*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`=` is an [assignment statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements), you appear to be confusing this with a `==`, the [equality comparison operator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons).

The statements are entirely different:

```
self.name = name
```

assigns the value referenced by the local variable `name` to the attribute `name` on the object referenced by `self`. It sets an attribute on the newly created instance, from the value passed into the initialiser method.

The alternative statement

```
name = self.name
```

assigns the value of the attribute `name` found on self, to the local variable `name`. It rebinds the local name (replaces the old value with a new). Once the method ends, the effects are gone. You are likely to get an `AttributeError` as the attribute `name` doesn't exist on `self` at that point in time.

If `==` had been used, then *usually* yes, `name == self.name` is the equivalent of `self.name == name`. However, objects can override how equality is tested by defining a new implementation for the [`__eq__` method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__) so the two expressions *could* theoretically produce different results.

Answer (score 0):

```
class NewClass(object):
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
```

This assigns the instance variable `self.name` to the value of the argument which was provided to `__init__()` (in this case `name`)

```
class NewClass(object):
    def __init__(self,name):
        name = self.name
```

This assigns the instance variable `self.name` to the value of the argument `name`. This would throw an error if `self.name` was not assigned to something else earlier in the `__init__()` function.

Comment: I find the terms used very sloppy/incorrect. The first sentence is somewhere between vague and backwards.

Comment: @MartijnPieters My mistake - it is an instance variable, isn't it?

Comment: *Class variables* would more readily be interpreted as *class attributes*, attributes that are defined on the class itself rather than on the instance.